# How do I match words that contains exactly 3 characters but not the delimiters?

Tags: regex

I would like to find words with exactly 3 characters between random amounts of the same delimiter.  Here we are using underscores as an example. For this example I'd like to match `Mom`, `123`, `boB`, and `pIg`, but nothing else.

```
_Mom_
_123__
__boB_
___pIg_____
__1234_
_Mary__
_12_
__Hi___
__MomboBpIg___
```

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have at least one delimiter on each side?

Comment: `_([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})_` https://regex101.com/r/yEOxh7/1

Comment: Please add a tag that identifies the language you are using. Is the delimiter given? If not, is it always the first character of the string? What if the string were `"pig_"`, `"_pig"` or `"pig"`?

Comment: What do you mean by "characters"? What defines what is a character and what is a delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

##### These regexes, using advanced [*look around*](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444):

```
_+\K[0-9a-zA-Z]{3}(?=_)
```

##### [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQ84lx/1)

##### or

```
(?<=_)[0-9a-zA-Z]{3}(?=_)
```

##### [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rIixw3/1)

Answer (score 0):

With a `_` *wrapper* you can simply do:

```bash
_([^_]{3})_
```

`[^_]{3}` meaning: *"three characters that are not underscores"*.

[Regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/DQXw1k/2)

---

By using positive lookbehind/ahead:

```bash
(?<=_)[^_]{3}(?=_)
```

[Regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/rXXZPm/1)

Comment: I originally thought on this `[^_]` though I assumed alphanumeric given the examples, but **literally** your answer is the correct one :)

Comment: And I read again... now I know why I assumed it... it says "words" but then again, 123 is not a word :D

Comment: @JorgeCampos thank you for the augmentation. Yes I assumed `@` `€` or anything else but the wrappers `_` is also a *"character"* /symbol to be considered. But yes, worth noticing. When someone uses only chars from the English alphabet (without diacritics etc) and by mentioning wrappers I assume they just didn't consider other characters from other languages. Although there are ways to account for unicode categories as well, the proposed seemed simpler.